# putting letters with number inside lua variables

Tags: nginx, lua

I have this Nginx lua code which is used to encrypt numbers from 0 to 9 with its equivalent encrypted code ... ( see the example below )

and its working great , but i want to make it also encrypt Letters from A to Z.

I'm not familiar with lua so i don't know what is the best way to make it works !

```
      content_by_lua_block {
local bf = {}
bf[0] = '(((_<<_)<<_)'
bf[1] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))'
bf[2] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])'
bf[3] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*'
bf[4] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])'
bf[5] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%'
bf[6] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_'
bf[7] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_'
bf[8] = '(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))'
bf[9] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))'

local cookie = ngx.var.token
 for i=0, 9 do
 cookie = string.gsub(cookie, i, "'+"..bf[i].."+'")
end
```

Maybe something like that :

```
      content_by_lua_block {
local bf = {}
bf[0] = '(((_<<_)<<_)'
bf[1] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))'
bf[2] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])'
bf[3] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*'
bf[4] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])'
bf[5] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%'
bf[6] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_'
bf[7] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_'
bf[8] = '(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))'
bf[9] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))'
bf[a] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))(()>[])%'
bf[b] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))(()>[])%(()>[])%'
bf[c] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))(()>[])%(()>[])%(()>[])%'
...................
...................
...................
...................
bf[z] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))(()>[])%(()>[])%(()>[])%)%(()>[])%)%(()>[])%'


local cookie = ngx.var.token
 for i=0, 9 and a, z do
 cookie = string.gsub(cookie, i, "'+"..bf[i].."+'")
end
```

Comment: may be `bf["z"] = 'encdyptedz'` ?

Comment: What about this part which is used to perform the changes "  for i=0, 9 do
 cookie = string.gsub(cookie, i, "'+"..bf[i].."+'") " how to make it exchange also the letters ??

Answer (score 0):

I tried to rewrite your code:

```
local bf = {}
bf[0] = '(((_<<_)<<_)'
bf[1] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))'
bf[2] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])'
bf[3] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*'
bf[4] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])'
bf[5] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%'
bf[6] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_'
bf[7] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_'
bf[8] = '(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))'
bf[9] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))'
bf['a'] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))(()>[])%'
bf['b'] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))(()>[])%(()>[])%'
bf['c'] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))(()>[])%(()>[])%(()>[])%'
--
--
--
bf['z'] = '(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))(()>[])%(()>[])%(()>[])%)%(()>[])%)%(()>[])%'

local cookie =  "01sdz" -- ngx.var.token


-- first example
local cookie = cookie:gsub ( '.',  function (x) 
                                         local s = tonumber(x) or x
                                         if bf[s] then  return  "'+".. bf[s] .."+'"
                                         else return x
                                         end
                                     end  )

print(cookie)


-- second example

cookie =  "01sdz"
for i=0, 9 do
   cookie = string.gsub(cookie, i, "'+".. bf[i] .."+'")   
   -- may be use bf[i]:gsub( '([%%])', '%%%1') with escape escaping symbol %
end
for i= string.byte('a'), string.byte('z') do
 local v = bf[string.char(i)] 
 if v then
  cookie = cookie:gsub( string.char(i), "'+".. v:gsub( '([%%])', '%%%1')  .."+'")
 end
end

print(cookie)
```

result

```
'+(((_<<_)<<_)+''+(({}>[])-(()>[]))+'sd'+(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))(()>[])%(()>[])%(()>[])%)%(()>[])%)%(()>[])%+'
'+(((_<<_)<<_)+''+(({}>[])-(()>[]))+'sd'+(({}>[])-(()>[]))])*(()>[])%(((_<<_)<<_)+((_<<_)*_))(()>[])%(()>[])%(()>[])%)%(()>[])%)%(()>[])%+'
```

I updated my code, anyway the second example will help you

Comment: I have updated my post because it doesn't seems to understand what i mean !